# Trying new video drivers with Ubuntu live disk?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

Is it possible to change the video drivers on an Ubuntu 16.04 Live Disk?

I've had [trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850564/dual-monitors-only-work-in-ubuntu-16-04-1-gnome-when-set-to-different-resolution) with Ubuntu 16.04 and my AMD R9 380 with dual monitors. I have a working installation of 14.04.5 and don't want to mess with it because my dual monitors are working, however I'm still using fglrx video drivers and I would like to try the new AMDGPU drivers to see if I can get dual monitors working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself as the drivers in my Xubuntu 16.04 are working just fine, still I think you can load/replace drivers in a Live session. One thing though. You may want to consider to make use of a persistent Live USB. That way changes in the Live config are saved and survive a reboot.
There are many references in Ask Ubuntu how to create a persistent Live USB. Here is one: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=fullsearch&value=linkto%3A%22mkusb%22&context=180

Comment: That was what I thought about doing too. But every method I've found requires two usb thumb drives, or a thumb drive + dvd drive. I only have one thumb drive :(

Comment: @sudodus: are you able and willing to help Chris ?